# Why does SharePoint workspace attempt to connect to blugro4relay.groove.microsoft.com

Tags: workspace

I'm evaluating SharePoint 2010 and have been trying workspace, which seems to work ok. The only strange thing I've notices is I get a credentials box pop up saying it's trying to connect to "`blugro4relay.groove.microsoft.com`".

What is this connection for, is it needed/can it be switched off.

The box is asking for my own local credentials so may be being forced by a local proxy server and entering them allows Workspace to work fine.

I'm just curious/concerned about this connection and I can't find any information about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the 'Groove Workspace' feature within the SharePoint 2010 Workspace product. It makes a call to the Groove public server ('`blugro4relay.groove.microsoft.com`' in your example). 
There's more about it in this note: [microsoft support KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939806)

Comment: "The connection to the Relay server used by your account cannot be eliminated." see more here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2502051

Comment: That explains it. what's concerning is there doesn't seem to be a way to switch it off. I'm going to do some more reading...